# how to save pdf file in folder without save dialog c# windows application

Tags: c#

This is my code for opening a PDF file. I need this file to be saved to a certain location in my computer eg.: `@"c:\temp\"`

```cs
List<string> pdfFiles = new List<string>();

OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
openFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
openFileDialog.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";

if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    pdfFiles = new List<string>();
    foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog.FileNames)
        pdfFiles.Add(fileName);
}
```

Comment: But you never open any files. Do you just want to copy the files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `File.Copy` method to copy the file to its new location.

First, obtain the path of the file in the old location and desired new location.
Then, apply this method.

```
File.Copy(@"C:\old.txt", @"C:\new.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

add this Reference file - **iTextSharp.text.pdf**

```
 string Folderpath ="your path";

 using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Folderpath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                    pdfDoc.Open();

                   // Paragraph k = new Paragraph("Your PDF ");            
                   // pdfDoc.Add(k);

                    pdfDoc.Close();
                    stream.Close();



                }
```